# GridView_RowCommand not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im really new to ASP.NET Webforms...My issue over here is that I cannot fire the LinkButton Command `DetailsReportLink` in any way.. i tried binding in `!IsPostBack` but still no luck...
The Debug is not capturing anything in `GridView_RowCommand` method.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" CssClass="Gridview" runat="server"
                                Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand" ShowFooter="false">
                                <Columns> 
                                        <asp:TemplateField  ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="User Info">
                                             <ItemTemplate ><p style="text-align:left"><%#Eval("Name")%></p>
                                        </ItemTemplate>  </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="text-left" ItemStyle-Width="110px" HeaderText="Mobile No">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <p style="text-align:center"><%# Eval("MobileNo")%></p>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Key Gen">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# Eval("HishabNumber")%>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="70px" HeaderText="Balance">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# Eval("LoanTakerBalance")%>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="140px" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="DetailsLinkBtn" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MemberId")%>' CommandName="DetailsReportLink" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Details" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#3C8DBC" ForeColor="White" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3C8DBC" ForeColor="White" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           DataTable dt = objdalTransactionEntry.GetLoanReceivedByLoanTakerIdForLoanManagement(Sessions.Name.UserId);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView.DataSource = dt;
                GridView.DataBind();
                lblMessage.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                GridView.DataSource = null;
                GridView.DataBind();
                lblMessage.Text = "No Info";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

 protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    { 
//DEBUG DOES NOT REACH HERE
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "DetailsReportLink")
            {
                long MemberId = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Member/MemberCreate?ID=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(EncryptionDecryption.Encrypt(MemberId.ToString(), true)));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolute MUST remove the re-bind of the gv in your page load event. You load it ONE time on IsPostBack = False.

You do not and quite much NEVER EVER EVER will re-load and re-bind the grid in that page load event each time - you will blow out any possible code flow, and a re-bind will re-set the row command event. Remove your else code that re-binds the grid. The gv will hold its state just fine, and survive a post-back just fine, and retain its value(s). Do NOT re-bind the whole grid on each post back. In your case for some strange reason in the "else" for postback - true, you have code that nulls out the gv - that code has to go!!!